# SSRS Broken Embedded Image

Tags: image, reporting-services

I have a SQL Server Reporting Services report with an embedded image in the header. It works fine in preview mode and if I inspect the RDL file, it has the encoded image stream in there.

However, when I deploy the report to the server and view the report in the Report Manager, the image shows with a broken X icon.

Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my image was too large. Reducing it to 50x50 px worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my png image where it had alpha-channel transparency enabled.
Removing this (or changing the image format to jpg) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, changing the image from CMYK to RGB color fixed it.